# ASP.net download link sometimes pops up download window

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have an ASP.NET endpoint which takes a request for a file with some params, figures out which file to serve and does something like this:

```
...
if (File.Exists(zipPath))
{                
    string fileSaveName = "YourZip.zip";                 

    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                     "attachment; filename=\"" + fileSaveName + "\"");
    Response.TransmitFile(zipPath);
    Response.End();
}
else
{
    Throw404();
}
```

The problem is in both Firefox and Chrome (haven't checked IE) no download window opens up and it waits until its all downloaded then instantly downloads the file. Any ideas of why or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a strange reason I had the following code on the page that delivered the zip:

```
    private void SetPageCachingToZero()
    {
         Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
         Response.Expires = -1500;
         Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    }
```

This made no difference in Chrome or Firefox but meant in IE I had to click the link twice. First time it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a file save by using [the content-disposition header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519/en-us)